# Error Message Customization

Tags: civievent

Is there a way to change the error message that users receive when they try to register for an event online for which the registration date has passed?  Currently the message is:  ! ERROR  Registration for this event ended on April 25th, 2016 12:00 PM.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is Possible to customize the error, On your install, visit the Form Registration.php in CRM/Event/Form directory.

The the error message is found in the function checkValidEvent(XXXX). and the line looks like this

CRM_Core_Error::statusBounce(ts('Registration for this event ended on %1', array(1 => $endDate)), $redirect);

Comment: Great - might be helpful to add to the answer about the right process for customising rather than modifying core eg https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Directories - or maybe there is a good question like to that link to (searching)

Comment: started one here in case there really isn't an FAQ type question for this http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11547/how-to-add-custom-templates-tpls-or-php-files