# Add legal_identifier field to contact page and form?

Tags: forms, fields

I tried add legal_identifier field by custom tempelate. It worked for pages, but not for forms.
Then I added this code to sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Organization.php:

```
$form->addField('legal_identifier');
```

Now it works good in organization contacts, but I'm not shure if this is correct. Can I edit this file? What will happen after update?
Is there some better way? Can I use some hook? How?
Thank's, I'm getting started with civiCRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of strategies for customizing CiviCRM!  They have their advantages and disadvantages - but you should definitely be concerned about your change disappearing on upgrade.

The easiest change is to use a custom PHP page just like a custom template.  Details are available on this [wiki page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11547/how-to-add-custom-templates-tpls-or-php-files).  However, this is rarely a maintainable solution, because you'll need to compare your file to the original every time you upgrade and move your changes over.

A better solution is to [create an extension](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension) and use a hook.  The correct hook here is [hook_civicrm_buildForm](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm).  I would insert a simple conditional to check that the `$formName` is the one you want to operate on, and if so to add your one line of code.  This is far more maintainable.

Please join us at http://chat.civicrm.org in the #dev-newcomers channel and we'll be happy to help get you set up with civix or any other tools you need to create extensions!

Comment: Thank's, I used custom php. Create an extension is challenge. Maybe next time...

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply a civicrm custom field, that you could use in a Profile or a Webform (if you are based upon Drupal) ?